# creating folder structure hierarchy in json using mysql result set

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, hierarchy, directory-structure

the below table is used to store my folder structure parent id associated with child id , the child id who dont have any parentid  than it is 0, i want all folder structure of a particular user .

```
# id, cid, pid, userid
'1', '2', '1', '1'
'2', '3', '2', '1'
'3', '4', '8', '1'
'4', '5', '3', '1'
'5', '6', '3', '1'
'6', '7', '6', '1'
'7', '8', '7', '1'
'8', '9', '7', '1'
'9', '10', '8', '1'
'10', '11', '0', '2'
'11', '12', '11', '2'
'12', '13', '0', '2'
'13', '1', '0', '1'
```

result set for user=1

```
select * from rec where userid=1
# id, cid, pid, userid
'1', '2', '1', '1'
'2', '3', '2', '1'
'3', '4', '8', '1'
'4', '5', '3', '1'
'5', '6', '3', '1'
'6', '7', '6', '1'
'7', '8', '7', '1'
'8', '9', '7', '1'
'9', '10', '8', '1'
'13', '1', '0', '1'
```

now i need to generate a json hierarchy of this data like

```
{
    1:[{
        2:[(
            3:[{
                5:[
                ],
                6:[{
                    7:[{
                        8:[{
                            10:[]
                        }],
                        9:[]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]

}
```

Comment: Huh? The result set that you show doesn't need a recursive function. _"Now I need folder structure hierarchy in node"_ - So please show the actual desired output. And please show the code you've written so far. And, indeed, the actual JS structure that holds your input.

Comment: 1:[
{
 2:[
  {
   3:[
    {
     5:[
      {}
     ]
     6:[
      { 7:[
       {
        8:[{}]
       }
       ]
      }
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
]

Comment: why it not need a recursive function, if not then how to get the above json, because each cild is dependent on other